# How to pass command line arguments to shell script in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am trying to send a variable to shell script from jsp. 
i.e

```
txtstr="xxx"
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filename.sh txtstr");
```

or

```
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filename.sh 'txtstr'");
```

But it is taking argument as a txtxstr but not its value. How to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it is taking argument as a txtxstr but not its value.

because you are passing `txtstr` as string. It should be...

```
txtstr="xxx";
Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("filename.sh "+txtstr);
```

Comment: HI Its not working. null is passed as argument to shell script.